# How to remove endarrow on mxgraph?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I want to remove andarrow on edge and join the line

I want to remove endarrow on edge on mxgraph.
How can I do as below?
[orijinal is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFeRO.jpg)

[I want to like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8D0Z.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Codes below are from [official mxgraph tutorial](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/)

```js
var style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();
delete style['endArrow'];
```